# Win32 API Renderer Thread and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to get threads running in my OpenGL program. Right now I am just working on a prototype to present to my group. Essentially, I have to render a large piece of terrain, using the ::PeekMessage() function from the Win32 API, is producing choppy results. Thus I am trying to get a render thread to run that will continuously render, while the main thread handles all the input. I have the thread launch correctly, but somehow it is dieing off prematurely.  I can't figure out what in my code is causing it. My code base is small, so for anyone that has a lot of experience working with this stuff, I don't think it should be to hard to diagnose. The entire code consists of 3 source files, no more than 100 lines long, and can be found at.

http://99.116.251.16/code/WIN32/Vers2/

Specifically, my issues arises in ContrllerGL.cpp line numbers 21 - 76. That code is as follows:

```
void ControllerGL::runThread(){



/*
  * BEFORE RESIZE EVEN MAKE SURE TO GET DEMINSIONS OF WINDOW
  */

 RECT clientArea;
 ::GetClientRect(this->hwnd, &clientArea);
 this->wndWidth = clientArea.right - clientArea.left;
 this->wndHeight = clientArea.bottom - clientArea.top;
 char out[256];
 sprintf(out, "1) %d X %d --> %d", this->wndWidth, this->wndHeight, this->loopFlag);
 MessageBox (NULL, TEXT(out), TEXT("Message Box"), 0);



 /* 
  * BEFORE WE ENTER MAIN RENDERING LOOP SET OPENGL
  * FLAGS AND CLEAR ALL BUFFERS
  */
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glClearDepth(1.0);
 glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);                      
 /*
  * END OF SET OPENGL FLAGS AND CLEAR ALL BUFFERS 
  */

 /* 
  * Main Rendering Loop
  */

 //*/
 while(this->loopFlag){
  //*/
  ::Sleep(50);
  if(this->resizeFlag > 0){
   this->resizeFlag = 0;
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();  
   float aspectRatio = (float)((this->wndWidth)/(this->wndHeight));
   gluPerspective(45.0f, aspectRatio, 1.0f, 100000.0);
   glViewport(0, 0, this->wndWidth, this->wndHeight);
  }
  char out[256];
  sprintf(out, "2) %d X %d --> %d", this->wndWidth, this->wndHeight, this->loopFlag);
  MessageBox (NULL, TEXT(out), TEXT("Message Box"), 0);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);  
  glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
  glLoadIdentity(); 
  gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);         
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);      
   glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glVertex3f( 0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
   glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);     
   glVertex3f(-5.0f,-5.0f, 0.0f);
   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);     
   glVertex3f( 5.0f,-5.0f, 0.0f);     
  glEnd();
  ::SwapBuffers(this->hdc);                     
  //*/
 }
 //*/
 /* 
  * END OF MAIN RENDERING LOOP
  */
 ::wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
 ::CloseHandle(this->threadHandle);
}
```

Somehow at the top of the function my loop flag is true, but somehow by the time it gets to the loop it evaluates to false. The only reason why it should break is because the main thread that spawned it terminated. However, if you compile the program, you will see the main window is still alive.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all over the internet in pieces. Anyways, I will leave my code up at my site for anyone else who runs into these problems.

There were were two things wrong with my code. One I had to actually create a new ControllGL before I passed it to WinMaker. Once I did that it resolved all my issues. After my issues were resolved with that I had to learn that you can only have one rendering context per thread. Thus I needed to add these two lines to my thread function since it was called from the other thread.

`this->hglrc = ::wglCreateContext(this->hdc);`

`::wglMakeCurrent(this->hdc, this->hglrc);`

Once i did that it all worked. This will make more since once I get my commented code to the url above.

Answer (score 0):

Your instance of `ControllerGL` goes out of scope after returning from the function `initializeApp`, which makes any access to it's member data invalid. It's pure luck if it doesn't crash. Make the `ControllerGL` a member of your `WinMaker` class, that should keep it alive.

Comment: Line 23, of WinMaker.h contains a ControllerGL* graphixGL, this is used in the CreateWindowEx(), as the USERDATA. I also tried to move the ControllerGL cntrl in main.cpp to the global scope. I am still crashing whenever I try and use member variable inside my thread function. I agree with you though, it has to be going out of scope, which makes perfect since, as to why it crashes, or why the loop stops. I made your suggested changes but it is still a no go. Let me post my update code to http://99.116.251.16/code/WIN32/Vers2/. Give me about 1 min to get that up.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is it, but

```
(this->wndHeight)
```

May be 0 if you resize the window. A common safegaurd is to add 1 if 0

you also have

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

in your running loop which is already initialzed to be so in the above lines.

Perhaps you inadvertently called a copy constructor and have a shallow copy?

Comment: Hello Enabren, 
So I have modified my code and the loop is now working with out crashing, I needed to instantiate the ctrl inside of main.cpp before I passed it to WinMaker.cpp. The updated version can be found at http://99.116.251.16/code/WIN32/Vers2/. Now I am stuck because for some reason, I can't get the OpenGL functions to draw to the window. I have a previous working version, which can be found at http://99.116.251.16/code/WIN32/Vers1/. Here I have the end result, it is just way to slow once I expand the number of vertices past 256X256. Anyways, if someone can help me get understand...

Comment: How married are you to Windows GDI? GLUT is platform independent and gives me less woes. But reimplementing in GLUT may be too much work.

off topic, tabs are bad. As a personal preference I suggest soft tabs to 4 spaces to prevent "tab damage"